# Can't make Remote Desktop Connection windowed, always full screen

Tags: remote-desktop, azure

I need to connect to a remote machine (Windows Azure instance), but the only way to do so is by using a certain `.rdp` file. Trying to type the url or IP, doesn't work.

The problem with the `.rdp` file is that the connection is always fullscreen.

I looked at the file, and it's just plain text:

```
full address:s:OMITTED
username:s:OMITTED
LoadBalanceInfo:s:Cookie: mstshash=MyProject#MyProject_IN_0
```

I tried creating another dummy file with RDC, using the resolution settings I wanted, and then modified the Azure `.rdp` file to look like:

```
full address:s:OMITTED
username:s:OMITTED
LoadBalanceInfo:s:Cookie: mstshash=MyProject#MyProject_IN_0
desktopwidth:i:1280
desktopheight:i:768
```

but it still goes full screen.

The resolution on the remote machine isn't changeable:
[image: azure instance display settings]

How can I connect in windowed mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel dumb, I didn't notice that I can open the `.rdp` file in Remote Desktop Connection. Once doing that, I can use the Display tab to set the desired resolution.

[image: RDC connection settings]

At the same time, I also discovered that I can right-click on the `.rdp` file and select **Edit**. This opens it in RDC, where you can make whatever changes you want, and then just click save. Looking at the file in a text editor it looks like I was missing a few additional parameters:

```
screen mode id:i:1
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
```